# How to set UserAgent while uploading a file to AWS S3 in C# (AWSSDK.net)

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, agent

I would like to set UserAgent while uploading a file to Amazon S3 bucket. In the older version of AWS sdk there is property in ClientConfig where in we can set or get the UserAgent. But in the latest version it changed to get. So, how can i set this option in my application.

Programing Language: C#

SDK Version: Latest (3.3.5.2)

Environment: VS-2015 and Windows.

Comment: Call me curious... why would this be useful?

Comment: Hi Michael, We have requirement to set this info. Will find out why we need to set this. Btw, is it possible to change ?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, This is required for internal auditing purposes. We have internal tools which generate reports based on this flag.

Answer (score 0):

We also had similar requirement. We were able to solve it using reflection. Please note that this not a portable solution and it may break if you upgrade the AWS SDK library

```
        AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config();
        var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public;
        var fields= config.GetType().GetFields(bindingFlags);
        var userAgent = fields.Where(x => x.Equals("_userAgent") && x.FieldType == typeof(string)).First();
        if (userAgent != null)
        {
            userAgent.SetValue(config, "my-custom-user-agent");
        }
```